# How to make path specification of partition on 2nd internal ssd *short* -- easy to type?

Tags: partitioning, mountpoint

I used the Disks utility to format my 2nd internal ssd. I added a whole-device partition without a name, and added a filesystem (ext4) name. Everything's working ok: it mounts at startup; the filesystem shows on the desktop (although I don't require that; I mostly use terminal). I already copied 400G of files to it, which took hours, so I'd prefer not to reformat it.

Currently to access a directory I have to type, schematically:
`/media/my-user-name/partition-name/directory-name`.
I want instead to type /some-short-name/directory-name, where some-short-name is at most three letters.

Now, I know that the shortest mount point name, "/", is already taken :) Disks shows the current mount point as /mnt/long-gibberish-UUID. Being a relative Ubuntu newbie, I guess /media got into the picture because it's a default for non-root storage devices.

What should I do?

Comment: I mount my data partition to /mnt/data and then link default olders back into /home like Music, Documents and then some others I add. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change directory to [the file system in] your second drive, '**to**-drive-**two**', I suggest the following alias:

```
alias 22='cd /media/my-user-name/partition-name/directory-name'
```

Store it along with the already existing aliases in your bash configuration file **`~/.bashrc`**. (Activate in the current terminal window with **`source ~/.bashrc`**; It will be activated automatically in all new terminal windows that you open. So go to drive 2 with the command **`22`**

If you want to use a shortcut, it is called symbolic link in Linux, for example, you can have a link in your home directory (alongside `Documents`, `Downloads` etc) to the file system in your second drive,

```
cd
ln -s '/media/my-user-name/partition-name/directory-name' 2
```

Then you can use **`~/2`** instead of the long name when listing files, copying files etc.

Comment: Thanks, @sudodus, those two solutions seem feasible. What I did soon after posting was: `cd /` then `sudo mkdir a-short-name` then in the Disks utility I changed the mount  point to /a-short-name.  That seems to work, at least so far. Am I risking any harm from that?

Comment: @brec, It is not common to have a working directory for private files directly in the root, but it is possible. For example, `/mnt` is recommended as a temporary mountpoint. For long-term use, you can create subdirectories in `/mnt` and use them as mountpoints.

Comment: I gather that it's not common, but it seems it might be OK on a single-user system like mine. I notice that `ls -l` shows me as the user and group, and only the user has any access rights. I could chown it to root, but AFAIK the only applications that need access will have me as user.

Comment: @brec, Keep it like that, work as much as possible with your normal user ID. Use elevated permissions (with sudo) as seldom as possible.